# I'm not a book, but may be in libraries

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix is for great necessities,
My suffix is for dirty beasts,
My infix is for you and me,
My whole is found in libraries.

What am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Musty

My prefix is for great necessities,

> Must

My suffix is for dirty beasts,

> Sty = where pigs are kept

My infix is for you and me,

> Us

My whole is found in libraries.

> Musty = "lacking freshness or vitality; old-fashioned"

Comment: Correct, of course.

Comment: And here I thought the answer was rot13(furys (cersvk fur / vasvk ur / fhssvk rys))